# Spring MVC Content Encoding Error after adding gzip filter

Tags: spring, servlets, gzip, maven-jetty-plugin

I have configured a `GzipFilter` in my custom `WebApplicationInitializer` and when I try to access the website. It shows me,

> Content Encoding Error
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
>
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

The GzipFilter I'm using is from this blog,

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/gzip-servlet-filter.html

I can see the browser request gzip content. And for the files that are downloaded I can see the Response header `Content-Encoding:gzip`. But, I don't see why I get this error. Below is my app config,

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        //configuration code
        container.addFilter("GzipCompressionFilter",GzipFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

If I use the filter from this post,

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Gzip-Servlet-Filter-in-Spring-MVC

The request never ends and the files download partially and loads infinitely. What could be the problem?

I'm using maven-jetty plugin to start jetty with `mvn jetty:run` goal. Currently I'm using the above filters to serve GZip content from the server. Is there any other way in maven-jetty plugin to enable GZip compression? GZipFilter is deprecated and I can't see any [GZipHandler](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/gzip-filter.html) implementation for embedded jetty server. My maven-jetty config,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopKey>jettyStop</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9191</stopPort>
        <httpConnector>
          <host>0.0.0.0</host>
          <port>8080</port>
        </httpConnector>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What version of Jetty? (note, Jetty 9+ uses Servlet 3.1 which is incompatible with *all* Filter based Gzip implementations due to the introduction of Async I/O in the servlet spec)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I'm using Jetty version `9.3.7.v20160115`. So what is the alternative for GzipFilter in jetty version > 8. If `GzipHandler` is the alternative, I don't know how to use that in my embedded jetty configuration.

Comment: One example of GzipHandler usage -https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/GzipResponsesExample.java

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks, But Sorry I was wrong. I don't use the embedded jetty. I use [jetty-maven plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) goal [`mvn jetty:run`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal) to start my server. So I don't have a main method. And I use no xml for configuration since I'm using java based configuration. The only jetty configuration is on my pom.xml posted above. How can I use the example? Do I need to configure it in the `jetty-gzip.xml`?

Comment: It is dangerous to use `jetty-maven-plugin` for production, don't do it!  You **need** to produce an (installable and/or deployable) artifact and start your server outside of `jetty-maven-plugin`, once you have that figured out, then you'll understand how to get GzipHandler into place in the correct place.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Yes, I use jetty only as development server and tomcat in production server. Then I guess I have to switch to embedded jetty for using GzipHandler. Thanks.